# How do I make a border-left display outside the list marker in IE8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have an ordered list that I want to put a border on the left.

```
<ol class="steps">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
<ol>

.steps {border-left: 5px double #7ab800;}
```

In Firefox and Safari, the border displays outside the numbers for the `<ol>`. However, IE8 displays the border inside the numbers, right next to the text for each `<li>`.

I tried changing `<display>` to `inline-block` but that removes the numbering. I tried changing `list-style-position` to `inside` but that changes the indentation of the list without moving the position of the border. There are no floats involved. There is a `<div>` wrapping the `<ol>` but it is not styled in any way.

I'm stumped. How can I get IE8 to display the border the same as Firefox and Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting a div tag around your list and apply your class to the div instead.

Comment: This might work but is not ideal in my specific situation. I don't want to add non-semantic markup.

Comment: I can respect that, but as a web developer with extremely specific GUI requirements and impossibly tight deadlines, I more often than not solve problems like this with non-semantic markup, css trickery, and hackish javascripts.  In a perfect world I would agree with this sentiment :)